# Is there a utility that will convert POSIX to PCRE for PHP?

Tags: php, regex, posix, utilities, pcre

Is there a utility that will convert POSIX to PCRE for PHP? I'm somewhat confused by the PHP manual on PCRE, and while I'll try to find more info on PCRE, I was wondering if anyone had designed such a utility.

Or, if anyone would explain how to convert the following, that would also be fine:

```
ereg("^#[01-9A-F]{6}$", $sColor)
```

But please explain how it's done, not just tell me the conversion.

Comment: interesting you write 01-9, why not 0-9 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^#[01-9A-F]{6}$/", $sColor)
```

In this case you only need to add the two delimiters.

In perl you can write something like

```
if ( s =~ /x.+y/ )
{ print "match"; }
```

As you can see the actual regular expression is encapsulated in //. If you want to set an option on the regular expression you put it after the second /, e.g. switching the expression to ungreedy by default /x.+y/U
pcre now emulates this behaviour. Though you have to call a function you also have to provide the delimiters and set the options after the second delimiter. In perl the delimiter has to be /, with pcre you can chose more freely

```
preg_match("/^#[01-9A-F]{6}$/", $sColor)
preg_match("!^#[01-9A-F]{6}$!", $sColor)
preg_match("#^\#[01-9A-F]{6}$#", $sColor) // need to escape the # within the expression here
preg_match("^#[01-9A-F]{6}$", $sColor)
```

all the same to pcre, best to chose a character that doesn't appear within the expression.

Answer (score 4):

`preg_match("/^#[01-9A-F]{6}$/D", $sColor)`

Note the [`D` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). People forget about it all the time. Without it `$` will allow a final newline character. A string like "#000000\n" would pass. This is a subtle difference between POSIX and PCRE.

And, of course, `[01-9]` can be rewritten to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score -1):

By the way, PHP supports both PCRE and POSIX regular expressions. Here is the section of the PHP manual on POSIX regular expressions, so you don't have to convert them: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php

Comment: I'm aware about this. However, POSIX will be deprecated in PHP 5.3, so I was looking to just keep everything up-to-date.

Comment: This answer is outdated, could you update it? `ereg()` is deprecated now